# How to get the gdb call stack trace?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

I have a core dump and a file where debug information is stored, can I use gdb without using an executable file to get a call stack with the name of functions and lines?

Comment: What is the "file were debug information is stored"?

Comment: g++ source.cpp -g -o executable_file;  objcopy --only-keep-debug executable_file debug_file;  debug_file - debug information file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I use gdb without using an executable file to get a call stack with the name of functions and lines?

At least on Linux/x86_64, the answer is no: the info saved after `objcopy --only-keep-debug` is not sufficient; you also need the executable file.

This is happening (at least in part) because the `debug_file` does not have the `.eh_frame` section, which is necessary for unwinding on `x86_64`.

If you are debugging the core dumps yourself, there is no reason to create `debug_file` -- just keep the original executable with full debug info for debugging (you can still ship a smaller stripped file to execution machines).